# Is there a way to find the variants of a word stem?

Tags: marklogic

I know that I can use [`cts:stem()`](https://docs.marklogic.com/cts:stem) to find the root stem of a word, but there does not appear to be a function to do the opposite.

I would like to discover all the variants for a word.

For example, if I enter "run", I would get a list of words such as "ran" and "running".

I am surprised this does not appear to exist. Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of a function to do the opposite of stemming either. I can only think of feeding a dictionary to cts:stem, accumulating the answers in a map:map, and persisting that in the database for future reference. This repository might be of use for that purpose:

https://github.com/marklogic-community/dictionaries

HTH!